# Combining array into one string (matlab)

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have something like the following:

```
A = [1 2 5; 1 5 7];

B = A(1,:);
```

I output B:

```
B = A(1,:);

B =

 1     2     5
```

I am looking to combine what is contained in B into one single string:

```
1/2/5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('%d/',B)
```

This will give you almost what you want, it will have unnecessary `/` in the end.

```
>> sprintf('%d/',B)

ans =

1/2/5/
```

If you want to remove it:

```
st = sprintf('%d/',B);
st(end) = [];
```

As @hmuster points out correctly, it is possible to do it with `\b` , the backspace character.

```
st = [sprintf('%d/',B) sprintf('\b')];
```

However, as @AndrewJanke points out correctly, it could become a problem if this string is written into a pipe or a file. So use it with caution.

Comment: And as one-liner: `st = [sprintf('%d/', B) sprintf('\b')]`

Comment: @H.Muster quick question, what does '\b' do? I'm assuming backspace? If so that's awesome and i need to use it way more

Comment: I'd avoid that backspace. If you capture output to a file or pipe or string, it's going to have literal backspaces in it, which could interfere with further processing.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: Thanks for pointing this out; I never thought about this.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! Works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it done properly (IE reusable), there are two steps:

1. Convert your numbers to strings (this will allow later crazy values to be converted properly with `num2str` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html
2. Concatenate your strings horizontally (you can use MATLAB concatenation property A = [B C]), but the functional way is `strcat` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html